# Yii2 GridView default order by CASE WHEN

Tags: sorting, gridview, yii2, sql-order-by, case

I am using GridView to display some data. I need to add default sorting by 2 columns as follows:

```
(CASE
    WHEN (inbound_datetime IS NULL AND outbound_datetime < NOW()) OR (inbound_datetime IS NOT NULL AND inbound_datetime < NOW())
        THEN 9999
    WHEN (inbound_datetime IS NOT NULL AND outbound_datetime < NOW())
        THEN inbound_datetime
        ELSE outbound_datetime
END) ASC
```

If I add this code in the `ORDER BY` clause in the data provider query, then all of the other sorting options don't work because this condition is applied to the query itself.

I tried to apply the default sorting as I would to any other grid, but it is not working (the method searches for an attribute with that name):

```
'sort' => [
    'defaultOrder' => [
        '(CASE
            WHEN (inbound_datetime IS NULL AND outbound_datetime < NOW()) OR (inbound_datetime IS NOT NULL AND inbound_datetime < NOW())
                THEN 9999
            WHEN (inbound_datetime IS NOT NULL AND outbound_datetime < NOW())
                THEN inbound_datetime
                ELSE outbound_datetime
        END)' => SORT_ASC,
    ],
],
```

Is there any way to make this default sorting work and still keep the ability to use grid sorting by column names correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more thinking and have come up with a solution to this problem.

I define the query in my controller method which opens the view. So I added a condition that checks if sort parameter is passed to the get request. If it is passed, I create the query without the `ORDER BY` clause. If sort parameter is not passed (no column sorting is done), I create a query with the `ORDER BY` clause.
In my controller method:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->get('sort')) {
    $query = Travel::find();
} else {
    $query = Travel::find()
        ->orderBy('(CASE
            WHEN (inbound_datetime IS NULL AND outbound_datetime < NOW()) OR (inbound_datetime IS NOT NULL AND inbound_datetime < NOW())
                THEN 9999
            WHEN (inbound_datetime IS NOT NULL AND outbound_datetime < NOW())
                THEN inbound_datetime
                ELSE outbound_datetime
        END) ASC');     
}
```